# Qt QList does not append local Objects

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, qlist, qmap

I have a understanding-problem why following code does not store any QString-Objects into my QList

```
QMap<QString, QList<QString> >map;
map = QMap<QString, QList<QString> >();
map.insert("eins", QList<QString>());
QList<QString> listInMap = map["eins"];
listInMap.append("test1");
listInMap.append("test2");
QList<QString> copyOfListInMap = map.value("eins");
qDebug() << copyOfListInMap.count();
```

Output: 0

Comment: Have you heard about QStringList?

Comment: Yes i have, i used in this example QString-Objects to demonstrate my Problem. In the "real-world"-application i use an extra class without inheritance of QObject. Thats my fault, maybe i should clarify that in the opening post...

Comment: Neither QString, nor QList inherits QObject.

Comment: Okay lpapp, then my "example" problem represents my actual problem without any modifications.

Comment: @IrfanDANISH: please do not remove tags intentionally added, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is simple: **copy on write, aka. [implicit sharing](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/implicit-sharing.html)**

```
QList<QString> listInMap = map["eins"];
```

At this point, you have not yet got a hard copy, only a "reference". That is not fair in the standard C++ sense, but imagine it as a "shallow copy". However, when you start appending in here, the list will copied and the original will left empty. It is because QList is [implemented the way that is CoW (copy-on-write)](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/shared.html).

```
listInMap.append("test1");
listInMap.append("test2");
```

On a side note, you may wish to take a look at [QStringList](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qstringlist.html). While it inherits QList, it also has some additional convenience methods.

Now, you may be asking: `How am I supposed to fill my map in, then?`.

## Multi map

I would personally suggest to use [QMultiMap](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qmultimap.html) or at least `QMap` with [insertMulti](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qmap.html#insertMulti).

### main.cpp

```
#include <QMap>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>

int main()
{
    QMultiMap<QString, QString> map;
    map.insert("eins", "test1");
    map.insert("eins", "test2");
    qDebug() << map.count();
    return 0;
}
```

### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

### Output

```
2
```

## Single map

If you stick to the current approach, I would suggest to either append the value into a new QStringList with which you will overwrite the value, or hold a reference to the exact same list.

Having said that, in your case, it looks a bit overkill to even consider an external storage for insertion. You ought to do that right away in my humble opinion.

### main.cpp

```
#include <QMap>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>

int main()
{
    QMap<QString, QStringList> map;
    map.insert("eins", QStringList{"test1", "test2"});
    qDebug() << map.value("eins").count();
    return 0;
}
```

### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

### Output

```
2
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I will research about the implicit sharing - i think that contains the key-facts which I need for the bigger picture about Qt. Currently, I get a slight idea that only one "real instance" can exists of this listed classes of qt: http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/implicit-sharing.html
So i cannot have multiple pointer to one unique instance to access/modify it. The only thing what I don't understand is, why it work with the usage of references. But I think within the next hour the things get clear for me :) Greatly appricate for your help lpapp!

Comment: @blackworker: because in that case you do not create a shallow copy. You have only got a reference. In fact, it does not matter whether it is CoW or value copy, you only need a reference for such cases. But then again, I think you should not use an external variable for such simple cases in the first place. See my 3-4 lines above how much easier it is than your original "messy" code. :)

Comment: @lpapp It's all true, but in this case I think the problem is not that. The solution is the one that described by Andrey.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#operator-5b-5d) your sample should be changed as follow:

```
QMap<QString, QList<QString> >map;
QList<QString> & listInMap = map["eins"]; // use reference here
listInMap.append("test1");
listInMap.append("test2");
QList<QString> copyOfListInMap = map.value("eins");
qDebug() << copyOfListInMap.count();
```

Comment: That solves actual my problem, thank you Andrey!

But i do not understand why it won't work if i use a pointer, and not a reference. Furthermore I've also got no compiler warning about that?

Comment: @blackworker: Because of CoW, as lpapp has described in his answer